# Can anything be more than 100% certain?

Tags: statistics

If someone says something is 110% certain, does that mean they did their math wrong?

It's frequently used in a manner of speech, however I wonder if there is any mathematical basis for being more than 100% certain.

(Especially since 100% certainty seems extremely difficult to prove, but approaching 100% certainty less so)

Comment: For some people "100% certain" just means "pretty sure".  For those people "110% certain" is a meaningful expression.  This isn't math, tho.

Comment: No. You may want to read [this](http://liorpachter.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/the-tabular-hall-of-shame/).

Comment: People are terrible at judging percentages, and some extent of innumeracy is ingrained into common language. Even for "normal" percentages, the proportion of times people are correct when they say they are "90% certain" is very unlikely to be very close to 90%.

Comment: This question may be well received on Philosophy Stack Exchange....

Answer (score 9):

No. This is a rhetorical device called hyperbole, not to be confused with the hyperbola, which is a conic section. You can read more about hyperbole on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole

The topic (Rhetoric vs. Mathematics: ellipsis/ellipse, parable/parabola, hyperbole/hyperbola) has very detailed answers here: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/175756/73094

Comment: I'd say your note about the hyperbola/hyperbole is the comic section of your answer. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

No. The sum of the probabilities of all events in a probability space must be 1.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Theory